# Pass function pointer from main to function to function

Tags: c++, pointers

I've just learned pointer in C++ and I have an assignment. Part of it is to sort the time. So I would like to try pass function pointer from main into `void bubbleSort()` then pass it to `int compareTime()`

```
void bubbleSort(timeArr& arr) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size; i++)
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < arr.size; j++)
            if (compareTime(arr.t[j],arr.t[i], ascending))
                swap(arr.t[j], arr.t[i]);
}
int compareTime(time t1, time t2, int (*compare)(int, int)) {
    if (t1.year == t2.year)
        if (t1.month == t2.month) {
            return (*compare)(t1.date, t2.date);
        }
        else return ((*compare)(t1.month, t2.month));
    else return (*compare)(t1.year, t2.year);           
}
int ascending(const int a, const int b) {
    return b < a;
}
int descending(const int a, const int b) {
    return b > a;
}
```

I want something like this:

```
    int main(){
    //do stuff
    bubbleSort(arr, ascending);
    }
    void bubbleSort(timeArr& arr, int (*compare)(int, int)) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size; i++)
            for (size_t j = i + 1; j < arr.size; j++)
                if (compareTime(arr.t[j],arr.t[i], int (*compare)(int, int)))
                    swap(arr.t[j], arr.t[i]);
    }
```

Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. You'll have to change the call to `compareTime`. Use `compareTIme(arr.t[j], arr.t[i], compare)`.

Comment: The name of the function pointer is not "int (*compare)(int, int)", it's only "compare". All the other bits are the type.